# Full Linux system restore into live remote VM

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, remote, azure

Is it possible to do a full system restore into a remote Linux VM live?

Say the remote system was boot up as Ubuntu 15.04, then I restore a Ubuntu 18.04 full system to it, while the Ubuntu 15.04 is running, then the next time it boots up, the system become Ubuntu 18.04. Is it possible?

Because it is remote VM, so there is no way for me to boot into a Live-CD or anything so that I mount the VM's disk, right?

**Update/Conclusion**: *restore into remote Linux VM live is impossible*, because it is impossible to mount & edit the VM disk directly, not with Microsoft Azure that I'm using at least. Furthermore, kernel boot option `toram` is [only for live ISO/USB](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BootToRAM), but migrating to a new hard drive would work. Thanks @Xen2050.

Comment: Should be a way to mount & edit the VM disk, somehow, depending on the remote system

Comment: Thank @Xen2050, so basically you are saying that such live restore is impossible, and have to mount & edit the VM disk instead.

Comment: I'm not sure, it just might be easier to mount & edit the VM disk directly. There should be a way to get it to update from booting itself... maybe the kernel option `toram` would let you edit the "disk", leaving the running system in ram, I'd might as well make that an answer, just not sure if it's supported in a VM

Comment: It's **very dangerous**, but theoretically you should be able to upgrade Ubuntu through a terminal,. Y modifying sources.list and doing an apt-get dist-upgrade (You would need to upgrade to 15.10, 16.04 then 18.04)

Comment: Yeah @davidgo, It IS very dangerous. That's why I don't even bother to go that route, and ask this question instead. Thx anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you could use the kernel / boot option `toram` to copy all the system files to ram, then you *should* be able to edit the underlying disk however you want. That works for a live ISO/USB, so you can update / overwrite / remove the device that it was booted from. I'm just not sure if a regular Ubuntu install supports `toram` (apparently it doesn't), or if a VM would support it (it should).
- Even doing a regular boot it is probably possible to update all the system files, even updating a kernel without rebooting is supported now, I'm not sure if it was supported in 15.04. But easiest would definitely appear to be mounting & editing the VM disk directly.
- Another idea is to boot the old 15.04 system, and create a new disk (using a new virtual hard disk for the VM), format, mount & copy the 18.04 files onto the new disk, then boot from the new disk with 18.04 next time. Like migrating to a new hard drive.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess the final conclusion is that, _such task is impossible_, because it is impossible to mount & edit the VM disk directly, not with Microsoft Azure that I'm using at least. Furthermore, kernel boot option `toram` is [only for live ISO/USB](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BootToRAM), not normal kernel. So upvoting but not _the_ answer for now.

Comment: I thought that might happen, wasn't too sure if toram worked with a regular install, guess it's only for live systems on Ubuntu. I guess I'll edit a little, with another idea too

Comment: Ah, clever. Yeah, that should do it. THX!

Comment: "even updating a kernel without rebooting is supported now"  I believe live kernel updates only work for a select set of minor kernel updates.  I expect changing from a 15.04 kernel to an 18.04 kernel will require a reboot.

Answer (score 2):

(**Update 2018 Dec 9**:  If your VM has a "rescue" mode and VNC access, there may be a simpler solution, see bottom of post.  Original answer follows.)

> Is it possible to do a full system restore into a remote Linux VM
>   live?

Probably yes (in most cases).

The simplest way probably involves two reboots, rather than one.

It should be possible to do it with a single reboot, but it is probably not worth the extra effort.

> Say the remote system was boot up as Ubuntu 15.04, then I restore a
>   Ubuntu 18.04 full system to it, while the Ubuntu 15.04 is running,
>   then the next time it boots up, the system become Ubuntu 18.04. Is it
>   possible?
>
> Because it is remote VM, so there is no way for me to boot into a
>   Live-CD or anything so that I mount the VM's disk, right?

If grub2 is your boot loader, you can do the following:

1. Copy a live `.iso` file (as a file) on to your filesystem.
2. Edit `grub.cfg` to boot a kernel and init ram disk from the `.iso` file.
3. Reboot into the live OS from the `.iso` file
4. Perform the restore from the live OS environment.
5. Reboot into the restored OS.

(This may also be possible with other boot loaders, but I am using grub2.)

> **Update/Conclusion**: restore into remote Linux VM live is impossible,
>   because it is impossible to mount & edit the VM disk directly, not
>   with Microsoft Azure that I'm using at least.

If you reboot into a `toram` live ISO environment, you should be able to do anything to the VM's disk.

> Furthermore, kernel boot
>   option toram is only for live ISO/USB, but migrating to a new hard
>   drive would work. Thanks @Xen2050.

I expect migrating to a new drive would be *much* simpler, if your VM provider allows you to swap drives.  (My discount VM provider does provide that feature.)

Here is the `grub.cfg` fragment that I used to boot into an ISO file.  I appended this fragment to `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`, then ran `update-grub`, then rebooted.

```
menuentry "Lubuntu  18.04.1  Live ISO" {
  set isofile="(hd0,gpt4)/path/to/lubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso"
  loopback  loop  $isofile
  linux   (loop)/casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed  boot=casper  iso-scan/filename=/path/to/iso/lubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso  toram
  initrd  (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}
```

Strangely, after booting the above, the filesystem that contains the `.iso` file will still be mounted.  Unmount it as follows:

```
root@lubuntu:~# mount | grep sda
/dev/sda4 on /isodevice type btrfs (rw,relatime,space_cache,subvolid=5,subvol=/)
root@lubuntu:~# umount /isodevice
umount: /isodevice: target is busy.
root@lubuntu:~# losetup -a
/dev/loop1: [0029]:265 (/cdrom/casper/filesystem.squashfs)
/dev/loop0: [0028]:259 (/isodevice/path/to/lubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso)
root@lubuntu:~# losetup -d /dev/loop0
root@lubuntu:~# umount /isodevice
root@lubuntu:~# mount | grep sda
```

Given that the whole point of `toram` is to be able to remove the disk, I find it strange that I have to manually detach `/dev/loop0` and unmount `/isodevice`.  I may report this as a bug in Ubuntu.

The above approach assumes you can use VNC (or equivalent) to access the virtual screen, keyboard and mouse of the VM.  If you don't have VNC, you'll probably need to make a custom live ISO file that will bring up a network connection so you can `ssh` in.

**Update 2018 Dec 9**:

If your VM has a "rescue" mode and VNC access, and if your OS is Ubuntu, then there may be a simpler option:

1. Boot your VM into rescue mode.
2. Use rescue mode to write the live Ubuntu `.iso` file directly to the beginning of the disk.  (Warning: This will overwrite the partition table, so you will lose all access to all data that was previously on the disk.)
3. Reboot.
4. Append the `toram` option to string of options passed to the kernel at boot.  (Ubuntu supports `toram`.  Other OSes may not.)
5. The live ISO system will boot entirely into ram, and you will be able to completely reformat the disk.  (If you like, you can use the live ISO environment to perform a standard install.)

Here is an example command that will write the `.iso` file to the disk:

```
# wget -O - <url_of_iso> | dd of=/dev/sdX
```

Comment: Thanks mpb! especially the last warning paragraph  _"The above approach assumes you can use VNC (or equivalent) to access the virtual screen, keyboard and mouse of the VM. If you don't have VNC, you'll probably need to make a custom live ISO file that will bring up a network connection so you can ssh in."_ upvoting!